# What's the convenient key do delete something on Mac?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, javascript

I've developed a paint application on the web using **HTML5 Canvas** element and **JavaScript**.

The user can select stuff he drew and then delete it using the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key on **Windows** (which is convenient in Windows).

I've never used **Mac** myself, and I just found out that there is no <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. There is a backspace however (just as in Windows), should this key be used for this?

What's convenient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace ←</kbd> or on newer Mac OS X <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> is the equivalent for the delete key on Windows OS/KeyBoard.

There are application implementations on the Mac using <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> which is forward delete (on a portable Mac's built-in keyboard).

Implementing both is probably the best way to support actions that users on Mac expect to happen.

---

Reference (1): [OS X keyboard shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343) by support.apple.com

Reference (2) (a reverse one): [Mac OSX Preview: Disable the Command-Backspace “Move to trash” keyboard shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/222006/mac-osx-preview-disable-the-command-backspace-move-to-trash-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: Hm okay. Are general users familiar with this? Or just "super/pro users"?

Comment: Is that key combination regularly implemented by Mac applications? Would a new user to this program likely think to try it based on their previous expectations of the platform?

Comment: @lawls Mac users are, as well as Mac users coming from windows OS wanting the delete key back. :-)

Comment: I've also seen some applications using FN+Backspace, but usually those are applications that run on several platforms and do not offer a native Mac OS experience. E.g. Eclipse, Filezilla.

Comment: Thanks! I have made sure both Cmd+Backspace and FN+Backspace work.

Comment: @jff True that! Coming from a Windows experience to a Mac and trying to simply delete things is very confusing. But it' probably the same confusion coming from Mac to Windows delete implementation.

Comment: @lawls That's probably the best way to go ahead. Support both ways!

Answer (score 0):

I would personally want the backspace/delete key to work unmodified (i.e. without cmd, fn, or other modifier keys) for this particular function. Consider the fact that deleting photos in iPhoto uses only the unmodified delete key, and deleting songs from lists in iTunes similarly uses only the unmodified delete key. Inkscape (admittedly not an Apple software, though perhaps close to the flavor of your application) also uses the unmodified delete for removing selected elements of a drawing.

Here is a random reference I found, but haven't thoroughly read:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/applehiguidelines/Menus/Menus.html

This indicates that a delete menu item is expected to exist which "Removes selected data without storing the selection on the Clipboard." Furthermore, "Choosing Delete is the equivalent of pressing the Delete key or the Clear key."